# Issue in reading french word from text file in java/android

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream, bufferedinputstream

I'm trying to read a french file contents (character by character) and checking there ascii value to do some operation.Everything works fine containing english alphabet but for character like àéèé, i'm facing some issue.

For Example if my file content is   français,I'm getting an output as franÃ§ais.
Here,i'm attaching my code please have a look and guide me to fix this issue.

```
File file = new File("C:\text.txt");

fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

char current;
char org;
while (fis.available() > 0) {
    current = (char) fis.read(); // to read character
                                    // from file
    int ascii = (int) current; // to get ascii for the
                                // character
    org = (char) (ascii); // to get the actual
                                // character

    if (ascii == 10) {          
        resultString = resultString.append(",'"
                    + strCompCode + "'");
        dbhelpher.addDataRecord(resultString.toString());

        resultString.setLength(0);
    } else if (ascii != 13) { // other than the ascii
                                // 13, the character are
                                // appended with string
                                // builder
        resultString.append(org);
    }
}
fis.close();
```

Here i need to read french char as it is in text file.
Your advice will be greatly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well how is the text file encoded? It looks like you should be using an `InputStreamReader` with the right encoding (probably UTF-8) and just reading a line at a time. Note that ASCII doesn't include any accented characters. Also, please put more effort into formatting your source code in future.

Comment: Check this link, is about reading UTF-8 files: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-utf-8-encoded-data-from-a-file-java/

Comment: yes my text file encoded with UTF-8.

Comment: I went through the link you mentioned but found something that i cannot implement in my code i.e in.readLine().can you please help?

Comment: @PraneshSahu Please keep nice code formatting and do not add code that is unrelated to your question.

Comment: If my answer was helpful please consider to upvote or accept it, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `InputStreamReader` with `UTF8` encoding:

```
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF8");
```

I suggest you to use Apache Commons IO library. With one line of code you can read all lines from your file and then process them in `for` loop:

```
List<String> lines = IOUtils.readLines(fis, "UTF8");

for (String line: lines) {
  dbhelper.addDataRecord(line + ",'" + strCompCode + "'"); 
}
```

You can add it in `build.gradle` with:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
  ...
}
```